# mod_rewrite secure redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite

Struggling with mod_rewrite trying to redirect a non-secure page to a secure one. This works:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (help/returns) 
RewriteRule .? https://mysite.localhost/%1/ [R=301,L]
```

But this doesn't:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} (mysite.localhost|mylivesite.com)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (help/returns) 
RewriteRule .? https://%1/%2/ [R=301,L]
```

The URL it tries to give me is https://help/returns//

I can't seem to get the HTTP:host into the final RewriteRule line.

I need the host in there so I can use the same file for local dev and live deployment.

Most grateful for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^help/returns https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]
```

1. This rule will redirect all requests to `http://example.com/help/returns` to a secure (HTTPS) location: `https://example.com/help/returns` -- it will preserve full URL path + query string. You have too many conditions, rule becomes complex which is not a good thing when your server is REALLY busy (regular expressions are expensive).
2. I have replaced `%{SERVER_PORT} 80` by more proper `%{HTTPS} =off` (this especially useful if your site is run on non-default port, which is 80).
3. I have also removed HTTP_HOST matching part -- you don't really need it unless you have more than one domain name/subdomain bound to the same site. In case if you need this condition just add this line after 1st line: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(mysite.localhost|mylivesite.com)`

Comment: Many thanks LazyOne. I hadn't realised it's possible to put the HTTP_HOST in the final "destination"
(I'm using PORT 80 rather than HTTPS=off because I have an SSL offloading load balancer which doesn't use 443 for secure pages - it uses 8080)

Comment: @Geoff Just make sure the rule works fine for you before you mark my answer as accepted (I'm sure my rule is OK -- I did tested it, but your setup may be slightly different and it may need to be tweaked a bit, but extremely unlikely).