# htaccess rewrites for website and admin area?

Tags: .htaccess

Apologies I am new at this, I have a website which has a CMS but both need to be redirected to https, how would I go about doing this?

Examples of my URLs are:

http://www.mywebsiteurl.com/login/
http://www.mywebsiteurl.com/admin/

My current htaccess looks like this, is this correct? If not, how would I change it to redirect to https for both?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsiteurl.com/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

instead. You may check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611995/mod-rewrite-secure-redirect) for more information.